# $\space \lim_{n \to \infty} s_n(x)=0$ and $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1}s_n(x)\,dx=1.$ Possible for step functions?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions

**Question :** Show that there exists **step functions**

$\space$ {$ \space {s_n : [0,1] \to R }\space  $}${_{n=1}^{\infty}}$ such that for any $x\in(0,1)$ we have $\space \lim_{n \to \infty} s_n(x)=0$  and $\space \lim_{n \to \infty} ({ \int_{0}^{1}{(s_n(x)\,dx)} }=1.$

**Corrected approach for the Question :** for all $ x \in (0,1)$

Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be such that $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx=1$. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define $f_{n}:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ by
$$S_{n}(x)=
\begin{cases}
    n-nx & 0 \leq x \leq \tfrac{1}{n} \\
    0      & \tfrac{1}{n} < x \leq 1
\end{cases}$$

as I need to prove **such that for any $x\in(0,1)$ we have $\space \lim_{n \to \infty} s_n(x)=0$  and $\space \lim_{n \to \infty} ({ \int_{0}^{1}{(s_n(x)\,dx)} }=1.$**

$x \in (0,1)$ = $x \in (0, \frac{1}{n}] \space U \space (\frac{1}{n}, 1)$

**Case 1 :** for $\frac{1}{n}<x<1$

as $\space {n \to \infty},  \space  \frac{1}{n} \to 0$ and $\space \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} 0=0$

**Case 2 :** for $0<x \le \frac{1}{n}$

as $\space {n \to \infty},  \space  \frac{1}{n} \to 0$ and $\space \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} n-nx $

**but here’s an observation through number line for case 2 :**

as $\space {n \to \infty} \space  \frac{1}{n} \to 0     $ for a large value of n,  $\space \frac{1}{n}<x$ . $\space$  So , $\space \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} 0=0$

**Integrating step :**

$\lim_{n \to \infty}  $$\int_{0}^{1}S_{n}(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{1/n}(n-nx)\,dx + \int_{1/n}^{1}0\,dx$

$\space \space$= $\lim_{n \to \infty}[{nx}-\frac {nx^2}{2}]_{0}^{1/n} + (\lim_{n \to \infty} 0 = 0)$

$\lim_{n \to \infty}  $$\int_{0}^{1}S_{n}(x)\,dx $ = $\lim_{n \to \infty} 1-\frac{1}{2n}= 1 - 0$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} $$\int_{0}^{1}S_{n}(x)\,dx $ = $\lim_{n \to \infty} 1 = 1 $

Thanks for the response guys, I changed and took an  approach through your suggestion guys. Do correct if needed

Comment: $x^n$ is not a step function.

Answer (score 2):

Let $s_n = n\chi_{(0,1/n)}.\,\,$

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, I will go through it.

Comment: Hey @zhw I have made changes.. Please if you could check and let me know. Thanks for the help again

Answer (score 1):

First, remember that step functions are piecewise constant functions with finitely many pieces. So $g(x)=x^{n}$ is not a step function, but something like
$$g(x)=
\begin{cases}
    1 & 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{3} \\
    3 & \frac{1}{3} < x \leq \frac{2}{3} \\
    6 & \frac{2}{3} < x \leq 1
\end{cases}
$$
is a step function.

Here is an idea for you to think about. Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be such that $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx=1$. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define $f_{n}:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ by
$$f_{n}(x)=
\begin{cases}
    nf(nx) & 0 \leq x \leq \tfrac{1}{n} \\
    0      & \tfrac{1}{n} < x \leq 1
\end{cases}$$
What is $\int_{0}^{1}f_{n}(x)\,dx$? For a given $x\in(0,1)$, what is $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{n}(x)$? Can you apply this idea to make the desired sequence of step functions?

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, I will go through it.

Comment: Hey @MathIsFun7225 I have made changes, your guiding questions were very helpful. Please if you could check and let me know. Wheather my working makes sense?. Thanks a lot again